# Python 3 Enums with Function Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I noticed an oddity in the Python 3 Enums ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)).
If you set the value of an Enum to a function, it prevents the attribute from being wrapped as an Enum object, which prevents you from being able to use the cool features like `EnumCls['AttrName']` to dynamically load the attribute.

Is this a bug? Done on purpose?
I searched for a while but found no mention of restricted values that you can use in an Enum.

Here is sample code that displays the issue:

```
class Color(Enum):
    Red = lambda: print('In Red')
    Blue = lambda: print('In Blue')

print(Color.Red)    # <function> - should be Color.Red via Docs
print(Color.Blue)   # <function> - should be Color.Bluevia Docs
print(Color['Red']) # throws KeyError - should be Color.Red via Docs
```

Also, this is my first time asking, so let me know if there's anything I should be doing differently! And thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#allowed-members-and-attributes-of-enumerations) says:

> The rules for what is allowed are as follows: `_sunder_` names (starting and ending with a single underscore) are reserved by enum and cannot be used; all other attributes defined within an enumeration will become members of this enumeration, with the exception of `__dunder__` names and descriptors (methods are also descriptors).

A "method" is just a function defined inside a class body.  It doesn't matter whether you define it with `lambda` or `def`.  So your example is the same as:

```
class Color(Enum):
    def Red():
        print('In Red')
    def Blue():
        print('In Blue')
```

In other words, your purported enum values are actually methods, and so won't become members of the Enum.

Comment: It's annoying as this feels like a nice way to switch on functions, I guess perhaps you could define the enum and @singledispatch on the values, all these alternatives seem verbose...

Comment: @BrenBarn I think OP prematurely accepted this answer.  The linked doc on enum states `enumerations can have arbitrary values` as long as they follow naming restrictions.  Since OP did not violate the naming restriction, why is OP unable to assign a function as the value of an enum?

Comment: @BrenBarn From testing, `Red` and `Blue` are actually static class functions, not class methods as your answer states.

Comment: @BrenBarn please see my answer, would love your feedback https://stackoverflow.com/a/65119345/2359945

Comment: @RazzleShazl: All methods will appear as "class functions" if you access them on the class.  A "method" is just a function object assigned as a class attribute.  That's more or less the point of my answer: The documentation I linked to explains that descriptors (including functions) are an exception to the "arbitrary values" statement.

Comment: Ah I missed the part `descriptors (methods are also descriptors)`, got it.  As for the method vs function comment, it was confusing for me because your answer differed from my python print testing.  I figured you would update your answer.  Thanks for explaining this!

Answer (score 13):

You can override the `__call__` method:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Color(Enum):
    red = auto()
    blue = auto()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return f'<font color={self.name}>{args[0]}</font>'
```

Can then be used:

```
>>> Color.red('flowers')
<font color=red>flowers</font>
```

Comment: Am I missing something or will the final line always return red because of the fixed `0` index? ```return self.value[0](*args, **kwargs)```

Comment: Ah got it, so the enum members are assigned a tuple, and `value[0]` dereferences the function.

Comment: @RazzleShazl Thanks, your comment made me realize the correct solution is _much_ simpler!

Comment: Is there a way to define a unique method for each value

Comment: @Sam You could branch based on `self.name` in `__call__`?

Answer (score 6):

If someone need/want to use Enum with functions as values, its possible to do so by using a callable object as a proxy, something like this:

```
class FunctionProxy:
    """Allow to mask a function as an Object."""
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
```

A simple test:

```
from enum import Enum
class Functions(Enum):
    Print_Function = FunctionProxy(lambda *a: print(*a))
    Split_Function = FunctionProxy(lambda s, d='.': s.split(d))

Functions.Print_Function.value('Hello World!')
# Hello World!
Functions.Split_Function.value('Hello.World.!')
# ['Hello', 'World', '!']
```

Comment: Another strategy is to use `functools.partial` which avoids having to define a new class.

Comment: I would recomment adding `def __repr__(self):  return repr(self.function)` for debugging purposes, and updating metadata. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58714331/7262247

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `functools.partial` to trick the enum into not considering your function a method of `Color`:

```
from functools import partial
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    Red = partial(lambda: print('In Red'))
    Blue = partial(lambda: print('In Blue'))
```

With this you can access `name` and `value` as expected.

```
Color.Red
Out[17]: <Color.Red: functools.partial(<function Color.<lambda> at 0x7f84ad6303a0>)>
Color.Red.name
Out[18]: 'Red'
Color.Red.value()
In Red
```

Comment: I’d love an explanation of why this (and the FunctionProxy) work over the direct function assignment.

Comment: @nnutter because `FunctionProxy` and `partial` are not of type `function`

Comment: This works as expected. Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently, found this post, and first was tempted to use the wrapper pattern suggested [in the other related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58714331/7262247). However eventually I found out that this was a bit overkill for what I had to do. In the past years this happened to me several times with `Enum`, so I would like to share this simple experience feedback:

*if you need an enumeration, ask yourself whether you actually need an **enum** or just a **namespace***.

The difference is simple: Enum members are instances of their host enum class, while namespace members are completely independent from the class, they are just **located** inside.

Here is an example of namespace containing callables, with a `get` method to return any of them by name.

```
class Foo(object):
    """ A simple namespace class with a `get` method to access members """
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, member_name: str):
        """Get a member by name"""
        if not member_name.startswith('__') and member_name != 'get':
            try:
                return getattr(cls, member_name)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        raise ValueError("Unknown %r member: %r" % (cls.__name__, member_name))

    # -- the "members" --

    a = 1

    @staticmethod
    def welcome(name):
        return "greetings, %s!" % name

    @staticmethod
    def wave(name):
        return "(silently waving, %s)" % name


w = Foo.get('welcome')
a = Foo.get('a')
Foo.get('unknown')  # ValueError: Unknown 'Foo' member: 'unknown'
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576596/is-it-a-good-idea-to-using-class-as-a-namespace-in-python) on namespaces.

Comment: I see you've been through enum hell and came out with a robust solution. :) With your experience, could you see what I might be missing with my simple answer? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65119345/2359945)  I'm worried that I'm missing some edge case etc.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RazzleShazl , it seems that BrenBarn pointed at least one issue with your answer: your enum members are tuples, not functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make it work without `partial`, `FunctionProxy` or anything like that, but you have to go deep into metaclasses and the implementation of `Enum`. Building on the other answers, this works:

```py
from enum import Enum, EnumType, _EnumDict, member
import inspect


class _ExtendedEnumType(EnumType):
    # Autowraps class-level functions/lambdas in enum with member, so they behave as one would expect
    # I.e. be a member with name and value instead of becoming a method
    # This is a hack, going deep into the internals of the enum class
    # and performing an open-heart surgery on it...
    def __new__(metacls, cls: str, bases, classdict: _EnumDict, *, boundary=None, _simple=False, **kwds):
        non_members = set(classdict).difference(classdict._member_names)
        for k in non_members:
            if not k.startswith("_"):
                if classdict[k].__class__ in [classmethod, staticmethod]:
                    continue
                # instance methods don't make sense for enums, and may break callable enums
                if "self" in inspect.signature(classdict[k]).parameters:
                    raise TypeError(
                        f"Instance methods are not allowed in enums but found method"
                        f" {classdict[k]} in {cls}"
                    )
                # After all the input validation, we can finally wrap the function
                # For python<3.11, one should use `functools.partial` instead of `member`
                callable_val = member(classdict[k])
                # We have to use del since _EnumDict doesn't allow overwriting
                del classdict[k]
                classdict[k] = callable_val
                classdict._member_names[k] = None
        return super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict, boundary=boundary, _simple=_simple, **kwds)

class ExtendedEnum(Enum, metaclass=_ExtendedEnumType):
    pass
```

Now you can do:

```py
class A(ExtendedEnum):
    a = 3
    b = lambda: 4
    
    @classmethod
    def afunc(cls):
        return 5
    
    @staticmethod
    def bfunc():
        pass
```

Everything will work as expected.

PS: For some more Enum magic, I also like to add

```
    def __getitem__(cls, item):
        if hasattr(item, "name"):
            item = item.name
        # can't use [] because of particularities of super()
        return super().__getitem__(item)
```

to `_ExtendedEnumType`, so that `A[A.a]` works.

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338652/how-to-define-enum-values-that-are-functions/40339397#40339397).

`

Answer (score -1):

Initially, I thought your issue was just missing commas because I got the output you were expecting.:

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    Red = lambda: print('In Red'),
    Blue = lambda: print('In Blue'),

print(Color.Red)
print(Color.Blue)
print(Color['Red'])
```

output (python3.7)

```
$ /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 ~/test_enum.py
Color.Red
Color.Blue
Color.Red
```

@BernBarn was kind enough to explain that in my solution that a tuple is being created, and to invoke the function would require dereferencing `value[0]`.  There is already another answer using `value[0]` in this way.  I miss rb for this.

Comment: By including a comma, you are creating a tuple.  This means the value of the enum is no longer actually a function, but a tuple containing a function.  You can see that the value is not actually a function because, e.g., `Color.Red.value()` will not work.  You would need to do `Color.Red.value[0]()`.  However, depending on the OP's needs, wrapping the function in a tuple could be a workable way to get it into the enum; it just means you need to do an extra step to unwrap it before you can call it.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn for quickly providing feedback and for clearing up this for me!