# How to define enum values that are functions?

Tags: python, function, enums

I have a situation where I need to enforce and give the user the option of one of a number of select functions, to be passed in as an argument to another function:

I really want to achieve something like the following:

```
from enum import Enum

#Trivial Function 1
def functionA():
    pass

#Trivial Function 2
def functionB():
    pass

#This is not allowed (as far as i can tell the values should be integers)
#But pseudocode for what I am after
class AvailableFunctions(Enum):
    OptionA = functionA
    OptionB = functionB
```

So the following can be executed:

```
def myUserFunction(theFunction = AvailableFunctions.OptionA):
   #Type Check
   assert isinstance(theFunction,AvailableFunctions) 

   #Execute the actual function held as value in the enum or equivalent
   return theFunction.value()
```

Comment: Another option: put the functions in a dict, with the function name as the key.

Comment: You discovered the edge case of enums... when python builds a class it adds the functional attributes as methods of the class. That's why they don't end up as values of the `Enum`. As I show in my answer it is easy to "fool" the interpreter into not making those as methods.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your assumption is **wrong**. Values can be arbitrary, they are **not** limited to integers. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#allowed-members-and-attributes-of-enumerations):

> The examples above use integers for enumeration values. Using integers
>   is short and handy (and provided by default by the Functional API),
>   but not strictly enforced. In the vast majority of use-cases, one
>   doesn’t care what the actual value of an enumeration is. **But if the
>   value is important, enumerations can have arbitrary values.**

*However* the issue with functions is that they are considered to be method definitions instead of attributes!

```
In [1]: from enum import Enum

In [2]: def f(self, *args):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [3]: class MyEnum(Enum):
   ...:     a = f
   ...:     def b(self, *args):
   ...:         print(self, args)
   ...:         

In [4]: list(MyEnum)  # it has no values
Out[4]: []

In [5]: MyEnum.a
Out[5]: <function __main__.f>

In [6]: MyEnum.b
Out[6]: <function __main__.MyEnum.b>
```

You can work around this by using a wrapper class or just `functools.partial` or (only in Python2) `staticmethod`:

```
from functools import partial

class MyEnum(Enum):
    OptionA = partial(functionA)
    OptionB = staticmethod(functionB)
```

Sample run:

```
In [7]: from functools import partial

In [8]: class MyEnum2(Enum):
   ...:     a = partial(f)
   ...:     def b(self, *args):
   ...:         print(self, args)
   ...:         

In [9]: list(MyEnum2)
Out[9]: [<MyEnum2.a: functools.partial(<function f at 0x7f4130f9aae8>)>]

In [10]: MyEnum2.a
Out[10]: <MyEnum2.a: functools.partial(<function f at 0x7f4130f9aae8>)>
```

Or using a wrapper class:

```
In [13]: class Wrapper:
    ...:     def __init__(self, f):
    ...:         self.f = f
    ...:     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...:         return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
    ...:     

In [14]: class MyEnum3(Enum):
    ...:     a = Wrapper(f)
    ...:     

In [15]: list(MyEnum3)
Out[15]: [<MyEnum3.a: <__main__.Wrapper object at 0x7f413075b358>>]
```

---

Also note that if you want you can define the `__call__` method in your enumeration class to make the values callable:

```
In [1]: from enum import Enum

In [2]: def f(*args):
   ...:     print(args)
   ...:     

In [3]: class MyEnum(Enum):
   ...:     a = partial(f)
   ...:     def __call__(self, *args):
   ...:         self.value(*args)
   ...:         

In [5]: MyEnum.a(1,2,3)   # no need for MyEnum.a.value(1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Note that the `__call__` method should contain a `return` statement or else when you  call the functions, you won't get the intended response. I was stuck on that for 2 hours. Seems obvious in hindsight, but in case someone else gets stuck here...

Comment: @Logister Only if the functions return a value.

Comment: No need to import `partial`, btw, you can just do `a = staticmethod(f)` instead.

Comment: @mar77i That's right. I've edited the answer to also show that option. Thanks.

Comment: I did not get `staticmethod` to work, however, `functools.partial` worked flawlessly. Thank you for this clever solution!

Comment: I can confirm that staticmethod does not work, at least not with Python 3.6.
However `functools.partial` does work.

Comment: @VarunMadiath You are right, it works only in python2 with staticmethod. Clarified. The last example did "work", in the sense that you could call `MyEnum.a(1,2,3)` but that was simply because `a` was a staticmethod, it was not part of the members of the enum. In python2 it would have been.

Comment: I was able to combine the `partial` approach over `lambda` functions to build polymorphism, pretty cool!

Answer (score 11):

Since Python 3.11 there is much more concise and understandable way. [`member` and `nonmember` functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.member) were added to `enum` among other improvements, so you can now do the following:

```py
from enum import Enum, member, nonmember

def fn(x):
    print(x)

class MyEnum(Enum):
    x = nonmember(1)
    meth = fn
    mem = member(fn)
    @classmethod
    def this_is_a_method(cls):
        print('No, still not a member')
    def this_is_just_function():
        print('No, not a member')
    @member
    def this_is_a_member(x):
        print('Now a member!', x)
```

And now

```
>>> list(MyEnum)
[<MyEnum.mem: <function fn at ...>>, <MyEnum.this_is_a_member: <function MyEnum.this_is_a_member at ...>>]

>>> MyEnum.meth(1)
1

>>> MyEnum.mem(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'MyEnum' object is not callable

>>> MyEnum.mem.value(1)
1

>>> MyEnum.this_is_a_method()
No, still not a member

>>> MyEnum.this_is_just_function()
No, not a member

>>> MyEnum.this_is_a_member()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'MyEnum' object is not callable

>>> MyEnum.this_is_a_member.value(1)
Now a member! 1

>>> MyEnum.x
1
```

Of course, you can add `__call__` to avoid explicit `.value` calls:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    ...
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.value(*args, **kwargs)
```

and now

```
>>> MyEnum.mem(1)
1
```

Note that this cannot be typed correctly unless all your enum member functions share the same signature.

Answer (score 7):

Another less clunky solution is to put the functions in a tuple. As Bakuriu mentioned, you may want to make the enum callable.

```py
from enum import Enum

def functionA():
    pass

def functionB():
    pass

class AvailableFunctions(Enum):
    OptionA = (functionA,)
    OptionB = (functionB,)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.value[0](*args, **kwargs)
```

Now you can use it like this:

```py
AvailableFunctions.OptionA() # calls functionA
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of [Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40339397/10325051)... If you use the wrapper approach like above you loose information about the original function like `__name__`, `__repr__`
and so on after wrapping it. This will cause problems for example if you want to use sphinx for generation of source code documentation. Therefore add the following to your wrapper class.

```py
class wrapper:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        functools.update_wrapper(self, function)
    def __call__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.function.__repr__()
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of [@bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40339397/95750)'s approach, I just want to highlight that we can also use dictionaries of multiple functions as values and have a broader polymorphism, similar to enums in Java. Here is a fictitious example to show what I mean:

```
from enum import Enum, unique

@unique
class MyEnum(Enum):
    test = {'execute': lambda o: o.test()}
    prod = {'execute': lambda o: o.prod()}

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[name]
        elif not name.startswith("_"):
            value = self.__dict__['_value_']
            return value[name]
        raise AttributeError(name)

class Executor:
    def __init__(self, mode: MyEnum):
        self.mode = mode

    def test(self):
        print('test run')

    def prod(self):
        print('prod run')

    def execute(self):
        self.mode.execute(self)

Executor(MyEnum.test).execute()
Executor(MyEnum.prod).execute()
```

Obviously, the dictionary approach provides no additional benefit when there is only a single function, so use this approach when there are multiple functions. Ensure that the keys are uniform across all values as otherwise, the usage won't be polymorphic.

The `__getattr__` method is optional, it is only there for syntactic sugar (i.e., without it, `mode.execute()` would become `mode.value['execute']()`.

Since dictionaries can't be made readonly, using `namedtuple` would be better and require only minor changes to the above.

```
from enum import Enum, unique
from collections import namedtuple

EnumType = namedtuple("EnumType", "execute")

@unique
class MyEnum(Enum):
    test = EnumType(lambda o: o.test())
    prod = EnumType(lambda o: o.prod())

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[name]
        elif not name.startswith("_"):
            value = self.__dict__['_value_']
            return getattr(value, name)
        raise AttributeError(name)
```

Comment: I just understood what syntactic sugar is thanks to your example, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this: there a way to make it work without `partial` or `member` in downstream code, but you have to go deep into metaclasses and the implementation of `Enum`. Building on the other answers, this works:

```py
from enum import Enum, EnumType, _EnumDict, member
import inspect


class _ExtendedEnumType(EnumType):
    # Autowraps class-level functions/lambdas in enum with member, so they behave as one would expect
    # I.e. be a member with name and value instead of becoming a method
    # This is a hack, going deep into the internals of the enum class
    # and performing an open-heart surgery on it...
    def __new__(metacls, cls: str, bases, classdict: _EnumDict, *, boundary=None, _simple=False, **kwds):
        non_members = set(classdict).difference(classdict._member_names)
        for k in non_members:
            if not k.startswith("_"):
                if classdict[k].__class__ in [classmethod, staticmethod]:
                    continue
                # instance methods don't make sense for enums, and may break callable enums
                if "self" in inspect.signature(classdict[k]).parameters:
                    raise TypeError(
                        f"Instance methods are not allowed in enums but found method"
                        f" {classdict[k]} in {cls}"
                    )
                # After all the input validation, we can finally wrap the function
                # For python<3.11, one should use `functools.partial` instead of `member`
                callable_val = member(classdict[k])
                # We have to use del since _EnumDict doesn't allow overwriting
                del classdict[k]
                classdict[k] = callable_val
                classdict._member_names[k] = None
        return super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict, boundary=boundary, _simple=_simple, **kwds)

class ExtendedEnum(Enum, metaclass=_ExtendedEnumType):
    pass
```

Now you can do:

```py
class A(ExtendedEnum):
    a = 3
    b = lambda: 4
    
    @classmethod
    def afunc(cls):
        return 5
    
    @staticmethod
    def bfunc():
        pass
```

Everything will work as expected.

PS: For some more Enum magic, I also like to add

```
    def __getitem__(cls, item):
        if hasattr(item, "name"):
            item = item.name
        # can't use [] because of particularities of super()
        return super().__getitem__(item)
```

to `_ExtendedEnumType`, so that `A[A.a]` works.

And I also recommend to make the callable enum, as proposed [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338652/how-to-define-enum-values-that-are-functions/40339397#40339397).

`