# Getting all values from an Enum, when values are callables in Python 3.7

Tags: python, enums, python-3.7, member, function-call

I have an `Enum` class in Python 3.7 defined as such:

```py
# activation functions
def relu(x: float) -> float:
    return x * (x > 0)


def sigmoid(x: float) -> float:
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))


class Activation(Enum):
    SIGMOID = sigmoid
    RELU = relu

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.value(x)

    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return [function.value for function in cls]
```

I have tried some approaches from other similar questions online, like `list(Activation)` and `Activation.values()` but always get an empty list. Any new ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338652/how-to-define-enum-values-that-are-functions

Comment: Hum, so my problem is not about the values. Nice. :D

Comment: The funny thing about this is that the function calls in enums work perfectly.

Comment: The enum documentation states that values can be of any type. There is a chapter about iteration and the behaviour of this program is different. In my opinion this should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @VPfB: The documentation states that descriptors are not converted to members, and methods and functions are descriptors.  This is not a bug.

Comment: @EthanFurman Well yes, I have found it in the section "Allowed members and attributes of enumerations". Thank you for correcting me. But please check the note in "Creating an Enum" (https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum) which states: _"Member values can be anything: int, str, etc."_ That is what I wrote in my comment now proved incorrect.

Comment: @VPfB: Good point, I'll get that fixed.

Comment: @EthanFurman Many thanks for all your work on the enum module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one way to solve this that wasn't mentioned in [the linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338652/how-to-define-enum-values-that-are-functions) without using `functools`, `staticmethod`, or a wrapper function.

The problem using **a function definition as the only value** of the Enum member, is that the Enum's `__init__` and `__new__` never get called. Having additional values, the Enum does get initialized as usual.

Proof as follows:

```py
import math
from enum import Enum


def relu(x: float) -> float:
    return x * (x > 0)


def sigmoid(x: float) -> float:
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))


class Activation(Enum):

    SIGMOID = 1, sigmoid
    RELU = 2, relu

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.your_func = args[1]

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.your_func(x)

    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return [member.your_func for member in cls]

print(Activation.SIGMOID(2))
print(Activation.RELU(2))
# 0.8807970779778823
# 2

for one_func in Activation.values():
    print(one_func(2))
# 0.8807970779778823
# 2
```

I don't think this is a bug (as suggested in the comments) because:

> However the issue with functions is that they are considered to be method definitions instead of attributes

What the several solutions have in common is encapsulating the function definition during the Enum (class syntax) value declaration.

Because of the above, using a "wrapper function" without `staticmethod` or `functools` wouldn't work, because it would never be called. Try substituting the following (neither `__init__` not `__call__` would be called):

```py
SIGMOID = sigmoid
RELU = relu

def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print("inside")
    return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
```

In conclusion, **perhaps the most pythonic approach** is wrapping the function definition in a list at declaration, and unwrapping in `__init__` at initialization:

```py
import math
from enum import Enum


def relu(x: float) -> float:
    return x * (x > 0)


def sigmoid(x: float) -> float:
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))


class Activation(Enum):

    SIGMOID = [sigmoid]
    RELU = [relu]

    def __init__(self, your_func):
        self.your_func = your_func[0]

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.your_func(x)

    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return [member.your_func for member in cls]


print(Activation.SIGMOID(2))
print(Activation.RELU(2))
# 0.8807970779778823
# 2

for one_func in Activation.values():
    print(one_func(2))
# 0.8807970779778823
# 2
```

Which saves calling `staticmethod` (some consider its use unpythonic outside a class definition). And saves importing and calling `functools.partial` - it involves unnecessary function call overhead with every member access.

Thus, the above approach might arguably be the most pythonic solution.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how and why this works, but this feels so much like a workaround. :D

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `aenum`<sup>1</sup> library you can use its `member` descriptor:

```
from aenum import Enum, member

class Activation(Enum):

    SIGMOID = member(sigmoid)
    RELU = member(relu)

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.value(x)

    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return [function.value for function in cls]
```

Which could also be written as:

```
class Activation(Enum):

    @member
    def SIGMOID(x: float) -> float:
        return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

    @member
    def RELU(x: float) -> float:
        return x * (x > 0)

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.value(x)

    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return [function.value for function in cls]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: This last one looks so much better. Thank you.

Comment: Then again we don't need the classmethod right? A `list(Activation)` will do, correct?

Comment: @SamuelNLP list(Activation) would give you a list of Enum members (name, value)  each being a singleton Enum class instance. If you only want the list of Enum values the correct way is implementing the classmethod, or populating a list comprehension. In this case, implementing the method saves verbose rewriting of the comprehension outside the Enum, which becomes more relevant if you write more elaborate versions of the method.

Comment: @bad_coder:  Thanks!  But it must have been fleeting as I don't see it now -- but I must be close!  :-)