# Python error "unbound method must be called"?

Tags: python

I started learning classes in python and wanted to build a simple calculator like so:

```
import math

class calculator:
    def plus(self, num1, num2):
        plus = num1 + num2
        print plus
    def minus(self, num1, num2):
        minus = num1 - num2
        print minus
    def power(self, num1, num2):
        power = math.pow(num1, num2)
        return power

C = calculator

num1 = raw_input("1st num > ")
num2 = raw_input("2nd num > ")

C.minus(num1, num2)
```

But for some reason when I run  the script it shows me an error stating "unbound method minus() must be called with calculator instance as first argument (got str instance instead)". I don't really understand what does this mean but I did try to play with the script and nothing changed. so what am I missing here?

Comment: You need to make a instance of calculator, like: C = calculator()

Answer (score 5):

You did not create an *instance* of your class:

```
C = calculator
```

`C` is now just a reference to the class, making `C.minus` an unbound method.

Create an instance instead by *calling* your class:

```
C = calculator()
```

Alternatively, make all your functions `@staticmethod`s, removing their `self` parameter (but do inherit from `object` in that case):

```
class calculator(object):
    @staticmethod
    def plus(num1, num2):
        plus = num1 + num2
        print plus
    @staticmethod
    def minus(num1, num2):
        minus = num1 - num2
        print minus
    @staticmethod
    def power(num1, num2):
        power = math.pow(num1, num2)
        return power
```

Now your `calculator` class is a glorified namespace which is [generally frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576596). If you are not going to use a class for tracking per-instance state, you may as well make all those `staticmethod`s top-level functions in a module instead, and avoid having to 'unbind' your methods.

Comment: Frowned upon by whom? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @DavidCullen It's less flexible than using modules and doesn't gain you anything, I don't think a reference is necessary.

Comment: @PeterWood: I understand why it is frowned upon. However, I think it is generally frowned upon to make that kind of statement in a StackOverflow answer without providing a reference.

Comment: @DavidCullen: You'd normally use a module for this. That documents the intent far better; why have the full infrastructure for a class *anyway* if you are never going to instantiate it and have to bypass the descriptor mechanism just to get functions again?

Comment: @DavidCullen: [Is it a good idea to using class as a namespace in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3576596)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am not arguing your point. However, your answer would be improved if you provided a reference.

Comment: @DavidCullen Martijn can pretty much serve as his own reference. I'm not quite sure what sort of reference you're looking for - something directly from the BDFL's mouth? A blog post?