# Organize objects using un-instantiated classes as namespaces?

Tags: python, namespaces

I've built a module to hold all of the common selenium expected_conditions which are then referenced throughout various tests. (The selenium portion of this example is not important, just the fact that I have a 'catalog' of a few thousand items.)

```py
# ec module
class EcHR(object):
    class sidemenu(object):
        hrfile: Clickable      = Clickable((By.ID, "sidemenu_HRFile"),       f"HR File")
        hrvistainfo: Clickable = Clickable((By.ID, "sidemenu_HRVistA Info"), f"HR VistA Info")
    class hrfile(__hr_search__):
        class actionmenu(__hr_search__.actionmenu):
            add: Clickable       = Clickable((By.ID, "NewHireLink"), f"Add {BUTTON}")
            personnel: Clickable = Clickable((By.ID, 'setEmpType'), f"Personnel Filter {DROPDOWN}")
            status: Clickable    = Clickable((By.ID, 'setStatus'), f"Status {DROPDOWN}")
            configure: Clickable = Clickable((By.ID, "configureLinkGen"), f"Configure {BUTTON}")
            reports: Clickable   = Clickable((By.ID, 'Reports'), f"Reports {BUTTON}")
            class addmenu(object):
                employee: Clickable = Clickable((By.ID, f'Employee'), f"Add->Employee {BUTTON}")
```

Sample reference to a given item in the ec module.

```py
import ec

    # navigation helper method for a given page
    def do_hrfile_nav(self):
        self.clickbutton(ec.EcHR.sidemenu.hrfile)
```

This works great; I can trace the usage of each object while still providing readability context for what the object is.

`self.clickbutton(ec.EcHR.sidemenu.hrfile)` tells the reader we are clicking on the sidemenu item `hrfile` on the `HR` page.  This is important to distinguish from the `ec.EcHR.hrfile` which is a different set of objects.

My question: **Is there a better/cleaner way to organize these objects?**  I'm using classes that never get instantiated. (which somehow feels awkward for reasons I can't articulate) These classes act solely as a means to reference them in an organized way.  Perhaps some sort of lightweight data object that has class-like structure?  (am I over thinking things?)

Comment: Duplicate -- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576596/is-it-a-good-idea-to-using-class-as-a-namespace-in-python) -- I will close after the bounty ends. Derp.  _(not sure why the other question didn't appear when I first wrote this question)_

Comment: I see the linked answer is divided between do it and don't do it (use modules instead). This is perfect for readability, does not pollute the namespace because establishes a contained hierarchy of names, and is much simpler than creating a tree of module files.

Comment: The awkward feeling is only because it is rarely seen. Somewhat related to this you may have Enums, namedtuples, and dataclasses.

Comment: @progmatico I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

I've got some ideas. 
It may be useful.

How about using functions as namespaces?

```
@namespace
def EcHR():
    @namespace
    def sidemenu():
        hrfile: Clickable = Clickable((By.ID, "sidemenu_HRFile"), f"HR File")
        return locals()

    @namespace
    def hrfile():
        @namespace
        def actionmenu():
            add: Clickable = Clickable((By.ID, "NewHireLink"), "Add {BUTTON}")

            @namespace
            def addmenu():
                employee: Clickable = Clickable(
                    (By.ID, f"Employee"), "Add->Employee {BUTTON}"
                )
                return locals()

            return locals()

        return locals()

    return locals()
```

I've changed every `class` to a function. And every function must be decorated with `namespace` decorator and must return `locals()` or any `dict` with custom key, val mapping.

Here's `NameSpace` class and `namespace` decorator.

```
from functools import reduce

class NameSpace:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name__ = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.__name__)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "NameSpace({})".format(self.__name__)

    def __call__(self):
        pass

def namespace(func):
    return reduce(
        lambda ns, kv: setattr(ns, kv[0], kv[1]) or ns,
        func().items(),
        NameSpace(func.__name__),
    )
```

The `namespace` decorator runs the decorated function and transforms the returned `dict` into a `NameSpace` instance.

How to access objects?

```
print(EcHR.sidemenu.hrfile)
print(EcHR.hrfile.actionmenu.addmenu.employee)
```

Comment: This is really interesting.  I'll have to play with it.  On the surface it appears to provide the same thing I get for free when simply using classes which are uninstantiated.  That said, from a readability standpoint, it's fairly clear these are 'namespaces'.  So maybe that's worth something.

Comment: Finally nice and easy to use improvement!